# Responsive Navigation Menu - jQuery slideToggle() not moving content down

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on creating a responsive navigation menu and everything's working well aside from the rest of my page content is not being pushed down when the menu expands.

I've made some changes so that the responsive width displays in JSFiddle--some things will look off as a result, but you'll be able to get the gist of it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxN5U/1/

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <a id="logo_link" href="#" target="_blank"></a>
    <div id="header"></div>

    <div id="nav" class="clearfix">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li><a href="index.html" class="current_page">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="submit.html">Submit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" target="_blank">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
    </div>


    <div id="content">

        <div id="main">

        </div>


        <div id="footer">
            <hr />
            <div id="footer_content">
                <div id="sm_icons">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/icon_facebook.png"  style="height:30px; width:30px;" alt="Facebook"/></a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/icon_twitter.png" style="height:30px; width:30px;" alt="Twitter"/></a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/icon_linkedin.png" style="height:30px; width:30px;" alt="LinkedIn"/></a>
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="img/icon_youtube.png" style="height:30px; width:30px;" alt="YouTube"/></a>
                </div>

                <div id="copyright">
                    <strong>© 2013</strong>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;


    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 25px;

    background-color: #003A70;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
}

#nav ul{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 960px;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', Helvetica, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a {
    box-sizing:border-box;  
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;  
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav li:last-child a { 
    border-right: 0;
}


#nav ul a:hover, #nav .current_page {
    background-image: url('../img/nav_selected_bg.jpg');
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#nav a#pull {
    display: none;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url('../img/main_bg.png');
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
    color: #971e23;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

div#wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
}


div#header {
    height: 75px;
    background-image: url('../img/top_banner.jpg');
    background-color: #f3f1f2;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}

div#footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f3f1f2;
    clear: both;
}

div#footer_content {
    padding: 0px 25px 50px 25px;
}


div#footer hr {
    margin-top: 0; 
    padding:0;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #999;
}


div#sm_icons {
    width: 135px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -7px;
}

div#copyright {
    width: 90%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    div#header {
        background-image: url('../img/top_banner_small.jpg');
    }

    div#copyright {
        clear: both;
    }

    div#sm_icons {
        float: none;
        width: 135px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    #wrapper, #content, #footer, #main, #nav {
        height: auto;
    }

    div#header {
        background-image: url('../img/top_banner_small.jpg');
    }

    #nav ul {
        display: none;
        height: auto;
    }

    #nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #003A70;
    }

    #nav a#pull {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-position: 25px;
            background-color: #003A70;
    }

    #nav a#pull:after {
        content: "";
        background: url('../img/nav-icon.png') no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: 10px;
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
var menu = $('#nav ul');
var menuHeight  = menu.height(); 

$('#nav a#pull').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
});

$(window).resize(function(){  
    var w = $(window).width();  
    if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {  
        menu.removeAttr('style');  
    }  
});  

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hxN5U/2/ remove the height of #nav

```
div#nav {
    /*height: 40px;*/
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 25px;
    background-color: #003A70;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #666;
}
```